# Meaning of big $O$ notation with 2 values separated by a comma

Tags: electromagnetism, conventions, notation, calculus, approximations

I'm reading Classical Electrodynamics 3e by Jackson. In section 1.7 he performs a proof of the Poisson equation in the context of the electric potential. Near the end of the proof, he writes
$$
  \nabla^2 \Phi_a(\mathbf{x})
    = -\frac{1}{\epsilon_0} \rho(\mathbf{x})\bigl(1 + O(a^2/R^2)\bigr) + O(a^2,a^2\log a) \nabla^2 
      \rho + \ldots,
$$
where $\rho(\mathbf{x})$ denotes a charge density, $R$ is a radius chosen such that $\rho(\mathbf{x})$ changes little within the sphere centered at $\mathbf{x}$ and bounded by $R$, and $a$ is a variable introduced to make the Laplacian well-behaved.

$O$ denotes [big $O$ notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). The meaning of $O(a^2/R^2)$ makes sense to me, but what does $O(a^2,a^2\log a)$ mean?

Comment: I hope someone here knows Jackson's conventions, but my guess is the coefficient is $O(a^2)$ for small $a$ and $O(a^2\log a)$ for large $a$, or vice versa; and if I'm right, you'd need context to know which way round is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Jackson, one can just replace $$O(f(x),g(x))=O(f(x))+O(g(x)).$$
NB: There might be other authors who would use the notation $O(f(x),g(x))$ to mean that it is both $O(f(x))$ and $O(g(x))$.

Comment: Is this stated somewhere in the text (or another of his publications)? Or, was it inferred from various examples of usage in the book?

Comment: $\uparrow$ The latter.